# how many instances of the class UserHandler will be created in this case?

Tags: java, spring, rmi

In our Application we are using Spring RMI concept .

I have a question as follows

There is one interface named UserHandlerI and its implementation class UserHandler as shown below

**Interface**

```
public interface UserHandlerI extends Remote {

public boolean add_user(String message) throws Exception;

}
```

And its **implementation class** (UserHandler)

```
public class UserHandler implements UserHandlerI 
{
public abstract boolean add_user(String message) throws Exception
{
// My business logic goes here
return true ;
}
}
```

Related to the above class and interface above , these were mentioned in xml file

```
<bean id="streamer-core" class="com.user.UserHandler" scope="singleton" />






<bean id="streamer" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://${${appl-host}}:${${appl-port}}/App" />
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.at.UserHandler"/>
        <property name="refreshStubOnConnectFailure" value="true"/>
        <property name="lookupStubOnStartup" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

I am not sure if i am missing anything from the configuration files ??

My question is , how can i know that how many (instances ) times the class UserHandler  will be created .
Will this be a singleton ?? Can i prove that ??

Thanks in advance .

Comment: sorry , its my typo mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `com.user.UserHandler` as bean with name `streamer-core` with singleton scope. So will be created only one **bean** `streamer-core` per one Application context. For more details read: [Spring Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton):

> Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring IoC container.

But it is related only for bean. After your set `com.user.UserHandler` as [SeviceInterface](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/3.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/remoting/support/RemoteAccessor.java#RemoteAccessor.setServiceInterface%28java.lang.Class%29) for RmiProxtFactoryBean you create one more instance for the `com.user.UserHandler`.

Instance for com.user.UserHandler creates in [RmiProxyFactoryBean#afterPropertySet](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/3.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/remoting/rmi/RmiProxyFactoryBean.java#RmiProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet%28%29) via [ProxyFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-aop/3.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyFactory.java#ProxyFactory)